# HP 500 Slate Support

Tags: gma500

has anyone installed Ubuntu on a HP 500 Slate? i have a HP slate 500 that runs poorly on win7 was looking for an alternate OS to run.

Thanks

Comment: Just [download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) the latest Ubuntu ISO image, burn it in a DVD or make a bootable USB and try it. You will never know till you try. Any problem, we are here Mundu wa Nyumba :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, not a HP500Slate, but I have had ubuntu installed on a device with the same graphic chip (GMA500):
Don't bother unless you are ready to jump through hoops or ready to be content with 2D-only

The GMA 500 has been a black page on the history of Intel.
It is not-quite-up-to-par on windows but it is worse in linux because of the very closed-spec/closed-source nature of it together with the reasonably buggy proprietary Intel drivers, both Linux and Windows.

There have been several reasonable working (out-of-tree) drivers from intel but they were made to work with certain kernel versions so they went out of date very quickly when intel stopped supporting them.

There is one open-source driver which works reasonably well but only 2D graphics are supported and almost no video acceleration, so this makes it unsuitable for the standard Ubuntu install (Unity desktop needs 3D-acceleration otherwise it eats your CPU for lunch).

If you really want to test it on another os than Windows7 then your only chance is, indeed, linux. There have been no drivers for other operating systems

Try a light version of ubuntu (without Unity 3D desktop) like Lubuntu and see how far it gets you, but there is very little chance that it will be better than Windows 7 (except, maybe, for OS speed).

If you want to fiddle with it, check out [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo/) page and [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/poulsbo) page for some info.
More descriptional info [here](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTMyODA)